# iOS simulator not scrolling properly (M1 + React Native project)

Tags: ios, react-native, apple-silicon

Running my React Native project on the simulator on my M1 MacBook Pro. ScrollViews do not scroll properly in the simulator. Only a problem on this setup with Big Sur and M1. Works on other computers and real devices.

When I swipe, the view scrolls but it takes a lot of "force" and view seems to lag as I scroll. Also, it stops as soon as I release the press (does not continue to scroll as expected).

Anyone else experiencing this issue?

Setup:

- M1 mac
- Rosetta-Terminal
- Xcode 12.2, CoreSimulator 732.18.0.2 (iPhone 11, iOS 14.0)
- React Native 0.63.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There seems to be a bug in the iOS simulator with scroll events when **not** running `arm64` images. See: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/668488

I was running into the same issue, and compiling to `arm64` resolves the problem.

To do that, you will need to either:

- Open and use XCode to compile instead of `react-native run-ios`.
- Or, use native arm64 nodejs by installing node 15.3 from source via `nvm install 15`. Make sure that both of `arch` and `node -p process.arch` in the terminal print `arm64`.

Note that you will need to disable Flipper in your `Podfile` to be able to compile to the `arm64` simulator target because of this issue: https://github.com/facebook/flipper/issues/1758

Additional info: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/30543#issuecomment-740161332

Comment: Thanks for your comment, although it didn't helped solving this issue for me.
For everyone that has this issue still: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65511051/9899193 <- this worked for me perfectly (it's basically running the simulator app in rosetta)