# iOS Simulator scrolls too fast on Apple M1

Tags: ios, flutter, ios-simulator, apple-silicon, apple-m1

I'm running a flutter project and when dragging any list or scroll view on the simulator, it scrolls with way too much force rendering almost impossible to get to the row I need.

This only happens in the simulator, and it seems to work fine on a real device. Also, this problem started when I had migrated to an Apple M1 MacBook Pro.

[image: Drag is minimal]

Any ideas?

Comment: if your problem is not in a device or creating a jank in performance i can't see a problem  here, probably you computer process way faster that an iPhone. just verify you performance is ok and that should be good enough.

Comment: Of course, it is a problem! It essentially makes the simulator useless for developing any app with a list.

Comment: recently I faced the same issue, it seems it was because one of the native plugins has arm64 in Excluded Architectures setting. Removing arm64 from this setting (keeping only i386) and wiping all data from simulator solved the issue. Abviously that it depends on plugin itself, some of them suffer from wrong binary usage on M1 chip simulators

Answer (score 81, accepted):

I experienced a similar issue but the problem, in my case, is not related to ***speed*** but something different.

Specifically, if you force your iOS Simulator to run under Rosetta you'll see that it works as expected. Not sure why, but this is what I'm experiencing. Always reproducible with 1.22.5 (stable).

To run in Rosetta, right click on Xcode and choose "Show Package Contents", from there you navigate to "Contents > Developer > Applications," There you'll find the Simulator app. If you right click on it and choose "Get Info", you'll find an option to run it using Rosetta.

**Update 14/9/2021:** Xcode 12.5.1 no longer needs the above workaround. Scrolling is working fine out-of-the-box.

**Update 29/10/2023:** Xcode 15.x and possible other versions in the past, unfortunately seems to suffer again of the infamous bug above.

I found that running Simulator with x86_64 emulation on Ventura, Sonoma as follow:

```
arch -x86_64 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/Simulator
```

workaround the problem.

Comment: This did help with a similar issue, where the scrolling was "laggy"/"stuttering". Thank you very much!

Comment: Fixed this very frustrating issue. Thanks, @valvoline!

Comment: This will make the simulator laggy on heavy apps though; performance won't be as good.

Comment: I'm using Xcode 13.1 on a M1 Pro and was still having this issue. Forcing the simulator to run under Rosetta fixed it. The M1 has been available for over a year, not sure why we're still dealing with these kind of bugs.

Comment: works thanks! ..

Comment: This works! However, I would remove the update about it working with Xcode 12.5.1. I'm on 13.2 and it is still broken.

Comment: Still seeing the same "super-fast scrolling" in the simulator: Flutter 2.8.1, MacBook Pro 16" with M1 Max, macOS Monterey 12.1, Xcode 13.2.1. Running the simulator with Rosetta fixed it.

Comment: I am using Xcode 13.2.1 but it doesn't work out of the box. However the Rosetta fix works. Any idea why the issue is still there?

Comment: I have this problem with an old project. Running simulator with Rosetta enabled fixed it!

Comment: This didn't become a problem for me (on my new M1) until I added the "Google Maps API for iOS" to my app. Enabling Rosetta for the Simulator is a viable workaround but I'm still looking for a solution. Running Xcode 13.4.

Comment: I'd updated my XCode last weekend, this problem persist and was fixed using the workaround of activating Rosetta

Comment: The iOS 16 emulator has no "Rosetta" option any more. But today I found out that the problem was caused by a single plugin that had "'EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'arm64'" in its podspec file. Replacing it with "s.pod_target_xcconfig = { 'DEFINES_MODULE' => 'YES', 'EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'i386' }" as in a new empty Flutter Plugin fixed the scrolling problem.

Comment: The scrolling bug still persists and there's no option to run the Simulator app using Rosetta anymore and the issue filed on the official Flutter repository has been closed. XCode version is 14.0.

Comment: Still scrolling bug exists. XCode version 14.2.

Comment: Bug still exists in iOS 17.0.

Comment: that's sad, I also face this with  iOS 17.0 and XCode 15.0.1. Anyone with with a solution

Answer (score 29):

[2023 Solution]

Just need to using x86_64 Simulator.
Follow these step on Terminal after close Simulator

```
1. Get list device ID:
xcrun simctl list

2. Launch:
xcrun simctl boot [deviceID] --arch=x86_64

Ex:
xcrun simctl boot 2BDDB447-AA8D-4BD4-8BFA-2F54363C2235 --arch=x86_64
```

Sometime Simulator will not automatic launch so you need to open it manually after step 2

Comment: This worked, it took a long time to run but is working. Not a perfect solution but a solution.

Comment: Finally, this works!!

Comment: I had another issue with the swipe scrolling abruptly stopping instead of getting a smooth scroll when I released the swipe gesture. This fixed it.

Comment: is there a way to automate this or have it always open with the x86_64 arch?

Comment: This works! It should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Not working on XCode 15. Anyone found a solution ?

Comment: @TSR I'm using xcode 15 rn and it still good

Comment: works for ios 15.2 xcode 15.2 Macmini m1 sonoma 17-1-2024

Answer (score 10):

[2022 update] The accepted answer no longer works, as there is no option in the iOS Simulator's Get Info dialog to run with Rotessa. Instead, what you can do is launch the iOS Simulator from Terminal using the following command:

```
arch -x86_64 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/Simulator
```

Comment: Gets exactly the same result. Still scrolling fast.

Comment: This answer did not work for me. I am using M1 MbPro, XCode 14.2

Comment: It doesn't work at all.

Comment: Not working on XCode 15. Anyone found a solution ?

Answer (score 3):

With me, this suddenly came up again with XCode 14/iOS 16. Fixed it in the ios/Podfile

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64 i386"
    end
  end
end
```

Remove arm64, so change the line to:

```
      config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "i386"
```

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't help me, as I receive such error instead: `error: the following command failed with exit code 0 but produced no further output     GenerateDSYMFile (...)` for one of my Flutter plugins

Answer (score 1):

Jank is completely gone once you run the app while targetting arm64.

**DO NOT DO THAT IF YOUR DEPENDENCIES CONTAIN NATIVE BINARIES** One such example is [google_maps_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter), they don't provide arm64 binaries and as such, attempting to compile the project on M1 natively will result in errors.

Open app's `ios` folder in xcode, click on `Runner` and edit `Build Settings` so that `Architectures` points to `arm64` and `Excluded Architectures` doesn't contain `arm64`
[image: how it should look like (more or less)]

*(even though these gifs are only 10 seconds long, they are over 2MB and can't be embedded, sorry for that)*

- `Runner` on `Intel` with jank: https://i.imgur.com/P4pswQn.mp4
- `Runner` on `arm64` without jank: https://i.imgur.com/zqGIe2L.mp4

Comment: This means that if my app is using such dependencies, I'm left with no option at all? Awesome.

Comment: You can clone the library and edit the podspec in such a way that will make it possible for it to run on ARM, but that's quite a lot of hassle https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/main/packages/google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter_ios/ios/google_maps_flutter_ios.podspec