# iOS simulator inertia while scrolling

Tags: xcode, scrollview, ios-simulator

I recently upgraded my laptop to Macbook M1 pro. I have a scroll view and it used to scroll with inertia when I use three finger to drag on my old Macbook air.

Now with the M1 chip there is no inertia when scrolling. I changed the iOS simulator to use Rosetta but still the scroll is not smooth like it used to be before.

Also is there any way to swipe a scroll view in iOS simulator via two finger swipe like we use in browser? My app has lots of scrollview and it's important to me.

Comment: is this happening all time or just for specific app you built ?

Comment: happening in default apps too

Comment: its scrolling fine in my real devices and android emulator.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As written in the solution for [iOS Simulator scrolls too fast on Apple M1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65476069/ios-simulator-scrolls-too-fast-on-apple-m1/65511051#65511051) the issue seems to be linked to the Simulator app running on Apple M1 code. Switching it to use Intel (=Rosetta) did solve the issue for me:

To run in Rosetta, right click on Xcode and choose "Show Package Contents", from there you navigate to "Contents > Developer > Applications". There you'll find the Simulator app. If you right click on it and choose "Show info", you'll find an option to run it using Rosetta.

Interestingly the problem appears for me only when I try to run an old iOS 13.7 Simulators. It seems that Apple has fixed the issue for more recent iOS versions (like 14.5).

Comment: Happening to me running on ARM using iOS 15

Comment: Issue is still there on iOS 15.2 simulator. The Rosetta trick helped, thanks.

Comment: Solved it for me in Simulator on iOS 15.5, thanks!

Comment: i use iOS 15.4 but its still not fixed by apple mbp m1

Comment: Solved it for me, thanks

Comment: Xcode 14 removed Rosetta option from Simulator...

Comment: Issue still there on iOS 17 simulator.

Comment: @FawadMasud: are you still using iOS 13 Simulators? I haven’t run them for a long time, so I don’t know if there are issues… Apple probably doesn’t run them either.

Comment: @pd95 I am using iPhone 15 simulator (iOS 17.0) on Xcode 15.0.1.

Answer (score 2):

There is no longer an option in the iOS Simulator's Get Info dialog to run with Rotessa. Instead, what you can do is launch the iOS Simulator from Terminal using the following command:

```
arch -x86_64 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/Simulator
```

Comment: This didn't resolve it for me :(

Comment: didn't resolve for me, both 15.2, 15.4 or 17.2 
Xcode 15.2 MacOS Sonoma Macmini m1